# Unable to Wipe my SSD from linux

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, umount

I have an SSD which I've installed Ubuntu on, it was completely clean. I installed it and encrypted it. I decided I wanted to wipe my hard drive for a new install without encryption. I'm unable to do this, I've tried using a USB boot loader and re installed although now the boot drive is broken and my hard drive has been divided. I cant re-unite it. I don't think it's a partition since GParted shows the division as a new drive. I really want to fix my Ubuntu installationbut I have been unable to do so.

It could be a virtual drive or something, but at this point I just want to clear my SSD

I've tried formatting it in windows, although the drive appears to have lost space and the partition does not appear. Even when I formatted the drive and booted it up in a different computer a broken linux installation still appeared which means that there is still something in the drive.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `dd` command?

It's a low level disk command, which means it can be very dangerous if you type incorrectly, so proceed with caution!

You will need an Ubuntu live CD or USB to boot from, or an Ubuntu installation on another disk, and you need to know the device name for your SSD, eg /dev/sda. It's really important that you get the device name correct.

This command will overwrite the drive with zeros, which should leave it nice and clean to re-format:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/(your-ssd)
```

Replacing (your-ssd) with the correct device name.

*I can't stress enough how important it is to get the correct device name, and type the command correctly, except by saying that `dd` is the abbreviation of **D**isk **D**estroyer!*

Comment: Great edit title @Fabby !